# How to increase the error limit in flake8 and pylint VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As mentioned above I would like to know how I can increase the no of errors shown in flake8 and pylint. I have installed both and they work fine when I am working with small files. I am currently working with a very large file (>18k lines) and there is no error highlighting done at the bottom part of the file, I believe the current limit is set to 100 and would like to increase it.

If this isn't possible is there any way I can just do linting for my part of the code? I am just adding a function in this large file and would like to monitor the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `"python.linting.maxNumberOfProblems": 2000` to increase the no of problems being displayed but the limit seems to be set to 1001 so more than 1001 problems can't be displayed.